# "put in contact with" versus "bring in contact with"

Tags: word-usage

I was wondering about the difference between "put us in contact with" and "brought us in contact with." Is it one more formal than the other? This is in the context of a person being introduced to a third person via email. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One is an *active* action by a person or an event.

> My best friend **put me in contact** with her attorney friend, who helped me with my case.

The other is *passive* as if the contact happened occasionally or involuntarily:

> Their job in hazardous waste removal frequently **brought them in(to) contact** with some very nasty material.

or that the contact is due to chance or random event:

> Some mysterious fate had **brought them in contact** with each other that dark and stormy night.